# Parse 2 dimensional JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a two dimensional JSON array where each element contains several attributes. The example below is intentionally simplified:

```
var map_data = { "1":
                      {"1":{"name":"aa"},"2":{"name":"bb"}},
                 "2":
                      {"1":{"name":"cc"},"2":{"name":"dd"}}
               };
```

I try to parse the data but `.length` doesn't work:

```
for(x=1; x<=map_data.length; x++) { 
    for(y=1; y<=map_data[x].length; y++) {
        // CODE 
    }
}
```

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not an array, they are simple objects, that's why you cannot use the `length` property.

You need to use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in) statement:

```
for(var x in map_data) { 
  if (map_data.hasOwnProperty(x))
    for(var y in map_data[x]) {
      if (map_data[x].hasOwnProperty(y)) {
        // CODE
      }
    }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` checks are because this statement iterates over all properties, inherited or not, and if something (like some JavaScript frameworks) augmented the `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` objects, those augmented properties will be also iterated.

You should know that this statement doesn't ensure anyhow the order of iteration.

I would recommend you to use a "real" array:

```
[
 [{"name":"aa"},{"name":"bb"}],
 [{"name":"cc"},{"name":"dd"}]
]
```

In this way you will be able to use the `length` property to iterate over the indexes.

Comment: +1 for pointing in the direction of a real array.  It never ceases to amaze me how many questions involve setting numerical index properties on objects.

Answer (score 3):

`hasOwnProperty` is used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object with no respect to it's prototype chain.

```
for(var i in map_data){
    if(map_data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        for(var j in map_data[i]){
            if(map_data[i].hasOwnProperty(j)){
                /*do whatever you want with map_data[i][j]*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `map_data` is an object instead of an array you need to use `for`/`in` loop:

```
for (var x in map_data) {
  // check for hasOwnProperty omitted for simplicity.
  for (var y in map_data[x]) {
    // CODE.
  }
}
```

But it's better to send that JSON as an array `[a,b,c]` instead of an object `{"0":a,"1":b,"2":c}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for .. in` construct:

```
for (var m in map_data) {
     // ...
}
```

Also, I must note that this isn't a "JSON array", but rather a nested object. JSON is just the string representation of nested JS objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps someone, its a example of c# and javascript:

c#:

```
List<List<string>>  list_array = new List<List<string>>();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string _myJSONstring = jss.Serialize(list_array);
```

/*in this case list_array is a list bidimensional, but can be a single array,
if you print _myJSONstring, this will show like this: "[["XX","AAAA"],["YY","BBBB"]]" */

javascript:

into a function that get the string from c#:

```
var a = JSON.parse(array);
    for (var t = 0; t < array.length; t++) {
        for (v = 0; v < array[t].length; v++) {
            alert(array[t][v]);
        }
    }
```