# How to iterate through a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value)

I want to iterate through a json object which is two dimensional ... 
for a one dimensional json object I do this

```
for (key in data) {
alert(data[key]);
}
```

what do i do about a two dimensional one??

Comment: Could you show us data ?

Comment: How to iterate through a json object? it would be easier having the data in front of my face

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488148/parse-2-dimensional-json-array-in-javascript

Comment: 2 dimensional can mean numerous things...  a little extra effort when posting questions would help. Also , doing a little searching would have likely given you your answer

Comment: if i alert(data) i get [object Object],[object Object] .... i get the desired output when i type alert(data[0][1])..but i want to alert all the elements ...

Comment: try `alert(data.key)` key being the key in the object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no two dimensional data in Javascript, so what you have is nested objects, or a jagged array (array of arrays), or a combination (object with array properties, or array of objects). Just loop through the sub-items:

```
for (var key in data) {
  var item = data[key];
  for (var key2 in item) {
    alert(item[key2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 not bad, caching `item` ;-)

Comment: it works but am getting the output twice ....

Comment: i get data[0][1] then data[0][2] , data[0][3] then again i get data[0][1], data[0][2], data[0][3] ... then data[1][0] and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you want

```
for(var i in data){
  for(var j in data[i]){
    alert(data[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (var key in data) {
   for (var key2 in data[key]){
      alert(data[key][key2]);
   }
}
```