# Draw a pie chart with Highcharts with datas error

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a pie, using Highcharts.

The data are provided in a json format : 
Here's the lines of my script :

```
    function myPie(d){
    console.log(d);
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
    series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Test',
    innerSize: '80%',
    data: d
   }
    ]
    ...
    });
```

The response at the console is Object { p0: "0.232697", p1: "0.259336", p2: "0.298506", p3: "0.177095", p4: "0.0323651" }

And I get nothing 
What's wrong ? 
How can I solve this problem.
Thanks for help.

Comment: You get nothing for at least 2 reasons, data needs to be an array, e.g. [{name: 'p0', y: 0.232697}, {name: 'p1', y: 0.259336},...] and data needs to be a number, not a string.

Comment: OK thanks, but how can I correct my code ?

Comment: By changing `d`, to have the format I wrote in my comment

Comment: I'm new to JQuery so, could you give me the way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: I am not going to do this for you, I have given you the format your data needs to be. You can chose to do this manually, or programatically. You could for example start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544551/how-to-iterate-through-a-json-object and here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: I'm not sure about your browser compatibilities, but this should be enough: `data: Object.keys(d).map(name => [name, parseFloat(d[name])]);`